# Вернуть середину строки js

Tags: javascript

Как мне вернуть середину строки? помогите не могу найти решение. Думал проверять на остаток от деления, есть или нет. Но не пойму как реализовать, прошу помощи:

```
getMiddle("test") // должен вернуть "es"

getMiddle("testing") // должен вернуть "t"

getMiddle("middle") // должен вернуть "dd"

getMiddle("A") // должен вернуть "A"
```

Comment: А где ваши попытки решения?

Comment: какие попытки ? я не смог придумать алгоритм как это реализовать.

Comment: Если кто не внимательно прочитал вопрос, я не ищу готового решения , я хочу понять алгоритм как это вообще можно реализовать. если алгоритм будет в виде работающего кода, будет только польза. что я упускаю?

Comment: Поздно пить боржоми. Вам уже 3 решения вашей задачи представили. После первого ответа нужно было писать про это. И это что `помогите не могу найти решение.`?

Comment: @Visman да не могу найти решение, прошу помощи. Где вы увидели что я хочу найти решение в виде валидного кода js. Вероятно сами придумали. Мне важно было понять как вообще решать подобные задачи, вот и спросил. псевдо код, алгоритм решения, я тоже подразумевал в вопросе.

Comment: @stas0k, тогда стоило вместо меток [tag:codewars] и [tag:javascript] ставить метку [tag:алгоритм]

Comment: принял к сведению. буду внимательнее. благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function getMiddle(str) {
  return str.substr((Math.ceil(str.length / 2) - 1), (2 - str.length % 2));
}

console.log(getMiddle("test"));
console.log(getMiddle("testing"));
console.log(getMiddle("middle"));
console.log(getMiddle("A"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение через преобразование строки в массив с последующим удалением элементов из начала и конца массива:

```js
function getMiddle(str) {
  var arr = str.split("");
  while (arr.length > 2) {
    arr.pop();
    arr.shift();
  }
  return arr.join("");
}

console.log(getMiddle("test"));
console.log(getMiddle("testing"));
console.log(getMiddle("middle"));
console.log(getMiddle("A"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычная проверка на четность/нечетность и один вызов метода объекта String:

```
function getMiddle(s) {
    if (s.length % 2 == 0)
        return s.substring(s.length / 2 - 1, s.length / 2 + 1);
    else
        return s.substring(Math.floor(s.length / 2), Math.floor(s.length / 2) + 1)
}
```

Но вообще, здесь действительно не принято давать готовый код.

Comment: Alexander, а зачем parseInt в else-случае?

Comment: В js ведь нет целочисленного деления, а так как в js я не эксперт, не уверен, что по числу с запятой substring будет работать правильно

Comment: Но да, лучше все же использовать `Math.floor`

Comment: что вот здесь происходит : return s.substring(Math.floor(s.length / 2), Math.floor(s.length / 2) + 1) объясните пожалуйста. Почему запятая?

Comment: `s.substring` возвращает подстроку, принимая два параметра - первый символ, **включительно**, последний символ, **не включительно**. Запятая потому, что два параметра. Для нечетного числа (к примеру - 5) делением на два выйдет 2.5. я хочу, чтоб было целое число, поэтому использую `Math.floor`, чтоб убрать дробную часть. В итоге остается 2. А после запятой считаю то же, только + 1, т.к. при нечетной длине строки ответом будет подстрока длиной 1

Answer (score -1):

```
function getMiddle(s){
    return s.substr(Math.ceil(s.length / 2 - 1), s.length % 2 === 0 ? 2 : 1);
}
```